# How to profile memory usage?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, profiler, valgrind

I am aware of Valgrind, but it just detects memory management issues. What I am searching is a tool that gives me an overview, which parts of my program do consume how much memory. A graphical representation with e.g. a tree map (as KCachegrind does for Callgrind) would be cool.

I am working on a Linux machine, so windows tools will not help me very much.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html), which is part of the Valgrind tools. [massif-visualizer](https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer) can help you graph the data or you can just use the `ms_print` command.

Comment: Thanks, the screenshots looking very great..., I think this is what I always wanted.

Comment: Building massif-visualizer on CentOS 7 is a bit of a pain, but it is worth it. [Instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49340854/560648)

Comment: As far as I understand, I think this answer should be noted as well (if the application is statically linked the "Valgrind" family tools won't work): https://stackoverflow.com/a/13591746/1971003

Comment: Also available as dpkg:
sudo apt install massif-visualizer

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported for MPI programs. Is that correct?

Answer (score 17):

Try out the [heap profiler](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html) delivered with [gperftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/wiki), by Google. I've always built it from sources, but it's available as a [precompiled package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/google-perftools) under several Linux distros.

It's as simple to use as linking a dynamic library to your executables and running the program. It collects information about every dynamic memory allocation (as far as I've seen) and save to disk a *memory dump* every time one of the following happens:

- `HEAP_PROFILE_ALLOCATION_INTERVAL` bytes have been allocated by the program (default: 1Gb)
- the high-water memory usage mark increases by `HEAP_PROFILE_INUSE_INTERVAL` bytes (default: 100Mb)
- `HEAP_PROFILE_TIME_INTERVAL` seconds have elapsed (default: inactive)
- You explicitly call `HeapProfilerDump()` from your code

The last one, in my experience, is the most useful because you can control exactly when to have a snapshot of the *heap usage* and then compare two different snapshots and see what's wrong.

Eventually, there are several possible output formats, like textual or graphical (in the form of a directed graph):

[image: Graph of memory usage]

Using this tool I've been able to spot incorrect memory usages that I couldn't find using Massif.

Answer (score 8):

A "newer" option is [HeapTrack](https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack). Contrary to massif, it is an instrumented version of `malloc`/`free` that stores all the calls and dumps a log.

The GUI is nice (but requires Qt5 IIRC) and the results timings (because you may want to track time as well) are less biased than valgrind (as they are not emulated).

Answer (score -2):

Use callgrind option with valgrind

Comment: Hello,

callgrind is nice tool, but it should be used for other purposes.

Probably you are meaning massif (https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)?