# Memory used by compiling a code

Tags: linux, memory, time

I use time command to measure the time used to execute a file as:

```
     time ./filename
```

My question: are there any command like `time` can give the memory used by executing an executable file in linux?

Comment: The alternative: simply run a command like htop in another terminal; and select your compilation process. Good enough to get you a basic understanding on resource usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to profile memory usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690800/how-to-profile-memory-usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/usr/bin/time -v ./filename`. It will print a lot of information including memory use.

Note:

```
time ./filename
```

Will use the shell built-in `time` command.

Comment: Thanks That helps a lot

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can click the check mark to accept the answer, if you think it was helpful enough.