# Measure the maximum memory usage during a function call

Tags: c++, linux, macos, getrusage

I have a Linux/Mac C++ library that performs a series of steps, in the form of function calls. I would like to measure the maximum memory usage during each step.

I am *not* interested in ad-hoc solutions like starting another thread that polls memory usage, running a profiler, etc.

So far I have found `getrusage()` is present on Mac and Linux and does return the maximum memory usage, however there appears to be no way to reset this maximum after each function call.

Is there any way around this limitation?

*Edit:* To be clear, I do not want to commandeer `malloc()`/`free()` and log everything. I want a solution that is suitable to keep in running production code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690800/how-to-profile-memory-usage

Comment: That is about adding profilers to my program which I stated I do not want to do.

Comment: Why adding? The second one is a precompiled package that is preloaded.

Comment: Added heaptrack in the linked question.

Comment: This is a library that will be distributed to other people. I don't want to force a profiler like `gperftools` on them. It isn't designed to be run in production use - only for debugging.

Comment: Linux and Mac OS are very different. Writing "Linux/Mac" doesn't magically make them similar. If against all odds there is a solution applicable to both platforms, congrats, you have won the lottery.

Comment: They *are* similar (e.g. they both have `getrusage()`). I never said they were identical or that any solution would work the same on both OSes. I am ok with `#ifdef __linux__`.

Comment: "they both have getrusage()". getrusage is POSIX standard, ru_maxrss is not. Both OSes happen to have ru_maxrss but the meaning is not the same (bytes or kilobytes?) and you cannot expect *anything* related to ru_maxrss to be the same.

Comment: I said they were ***similar*** not identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a browse through the Linux source code, and found [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f346b0becb1bc62e45495f9cdbae3eef35d0b635/fs/proc/task_mmu.c#L1118):

```
        /*
         * Writing 5 to /proc/pid/clear_refs resets the peak
         * resident set size to this mm's current rss value.
         */
```

I haven't tried it yet but it looks promising.

Edit: It was added in [this commit](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/12/10/312)

Edit 2: I have looked through the MacOS kernel source - the corresponding value is stored in [`resident_max`](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/search?q=resident_max&unscoped_q=resident_max). Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a feature to reset it.

Edit 3: On Linux you can obtain the maximum allocated memory using `malloc_info()` however there does not appear to be a way to reset it. It also relies on you using `glibc`.

Answer (score 0):

The `malloc` and `free` calls are more than trivial wrappers around `sbrk` and `mmap` system calls. This makes `getrusage` return something that is not in line with calls to `malloc` and `free`. Any non-trivial implementation of these functions will manage a free-list inside the process itself, before thinking of returning anything to the system.

The program calls `free` (or `delete` for that matter), and the memory is not immediately returned to the operating system (maybe never). The `free`-ed memory can be reused by the task, if it calls `malloc`, but not by other processes. This makes `getrusage` correct from the OS perspective, but not correct from the program perspective.

On Linux you can use [`mallinfo()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc)

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <cinttypes>
std::size_t memsize()
{
    auto data = mallinfo();
    return data.arena - data.fordblks + data.hblkhd;
}
```

Here, `memsize()` will return the number of bytes allocated from program's perspective. It takes into account the various allocation techniques, such as `sbrk` and `mmap`, and considers rounding up and overhead as part of the allocated memory of `malloc()` (and `new`).

With OSX things are not so bright. You can have a look into the [source code of apple's malloc()](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/gen/malloc.c), and specifically at `mstats`, which states in the comment:

```
/*
 * A Glibc-like mstats() interface.
 *
 * Note that this interface really isn't very good, as it doesn't understand
 * that we may have multiple allocators running at once.  We just massage
 * the result from malloc_zone_statistics in any case.
 */
```

This does not look very promising and:

```
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
#include <cinttypes>
std::size_t memsize()
{
    auto data = mstats();
    return data.bytes_used;
}
```

Does not look very good, according to my experiments. But it may be better than nothing, or just relying on `getrusage`. I think you are out of luck on OSX, unless someone can correct me.

Comment: This is all about getting the *current* memory usage right? I want the *peak* usage. Useful information nonetheless.

Comment: You can know it! Both Linux and Mac record this information (in terms of RSS which would be fine for my purposes). Additionally `malloc_info()` returns a `maximum` field which may be what I want but it is completely undocumented so I'm not sure yet.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "`getrusage` seems to be an approximation". I'm pretty sure it isn't.

Comment: @Timmmm forget about what I wrote, a mistake